# Elasticsearch Java API Client 7.16.3 BootstrapMethodError

Tags: java, elasticsearch, client

**PROBLEM**

Logstash java custom filter
The following error occurs when using the 'elasticsearch java api client 7.16'.

- java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
- Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair

The way I tried:

1. httpclient, httpcore jar Individual build
2. jdk 11 version build (default 8)
3. IP communication test between docker containers.

★ I have to use ELK 7.16.3 or higher version because of log4j vulnerability. ★

Help me, please..

**LOG**

```
nc-common-logstash | [DEBUG][org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient] request [HEAD http://elasticsearch:9200/] returned [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
nc-common-logstash | java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:194) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:307) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:258) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:248) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:317) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:301) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:276) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:143) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.ping(ElasticsearchClient.java:1188) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at org.logstashplugins.TmsConfigLoader.loadTmsConfig(TmsConfigLoader.java:76) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at org.logstashplugins.TmsConfigLoader.run(TmsConfigLoader.java:235) ~[logstash-filter-nc_netflow-1.0.0.jar:?]
nc-common-logstash | Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:254) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:328) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    at java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127) ~[?:?]
nc-common-logstash |    ... 10 more
```

**CODE**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.FieldValue;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.TermQuery;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.Hit;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.endpoints.BooleanResponse;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;

public class configLoader extends Thread {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    public void loadConfig() {
        RestClient restClient = null;
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = null;
        ElasticsearchClient client = null;

        SearchRequest searchRequest = null;
        SearchResponse<Object> searchResponse = null;
        try {
            if (this.esUrl != null) {
                // host: elasticsearch, port: 9200,  protocol: http
                restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(esUrl.getHost(), esUrl.getPort(), esUrl.getProtocol())).build();
                transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
                client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

                BooleanResponse pingRes = client.ping();
                if (pingRes.value()) {
                    if (this.logger != null) {
                        logger.info("ConfigLoader - Elasticsearch Connection Success");
                    }

                    // get config List
                    searchRequest = null;
                    searchResponse = null;
                    tmsConfigService.getList().clear();

                    searchRequest = createSearchRequest(this.indexPatternService, 0, 10000, "deleted", false);
                    searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, Object.class);

                    for (Hit<Object> hit: searchResponse.hits().hits()) {
                        String _id = hit.id();
                        Object source = hit.source();
                        if(source != null){
                            Map<String, Object> item = (Map)source;

                            item.put("_id", _id);

                            Service service = new Service(item);
                            tmsConfigService.getList().add(service);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (this.logger != null) {
                        logger.error("ConfigLoader - (ping fail)");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (this.logger != null) {
                    logger.error("ConfigLoader - (empty url)");
                }
            }
        } catch (java.io.IOException exception) {
            if (this.logger != null) {
                logger.error("ConfigLoader - IOException (error)");
                logger.error(exception);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ElasticsearchException exception) {
            if (this.logger != null) {
                logger.error("ConfigLoader - ElasticsearchException (search error)");
                logger.error(exception);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            if (this.logger != null) {
                logger.error("ConfigLoader - Exception (error)");
                logger.error(exception);
            }
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                    client.shutdown();
                    transport.close();
                    restClient.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    if (logger != null) {
                        logger.error("ConfigLoader - IOException (close error)");
                        logger.error(exception);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        this.loadConfig();

        while (this.isInterrupted() != true) {
            this.loadConfig();
            try {
                sleep(60 * 30 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                if (this.logger != null) {
                    logger.error("ConfigLoader - InterruptedException");
                    logger.error(exception);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GRADLE DEPENDENCIES**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:7.16.3'
    // implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.16.3'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.16.3'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer:7.16.3'
    // implementation 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:7.16.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.10'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.12'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: LOGSTASH_CORE_PATH, include: "build/libs/logstash-core-7.16.3.jar")
    // implementation fileTree(dir: LOGSTASH_CUSTOM_LIBS_PATH, include: "build/libs/httpclient-4.5.10.jar")
    // implementation fileTree(dir: LOGSTASH_CUSTOM_LIBS_PATH, include: "build/libs/httpcore-4.4.12.jar")
    implementation 'org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.2.7.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //testImplementation 'org.jruby:jruby-complete:9.2.7.0'
}
```

**ENVIRENMENT**

```
centos 7.7
logstash 7.16.3
elasticsearch 7.16.3
jdk 1.8.0_251
docker-compose
```

Comment: That error should happen because of an old version of httpcore or httpclient, but it looks like you have the [correct versions](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.16.3/jar) for your Elasticsearch client.